# React / Redux alerting best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, react-toolbox

I'm new to redux, and I'm rebuilding a fairly complex reactjs app using redux.

I thought it made sense to build a "feature" for notifications that would have a slice of state with like

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../../app/store';

export interface NotificationState {
    show: boolean,
    status: 'info' | 'warn' | 'error' | 'success',
    title: string,
    message: string,
    position: 'dash' | 'popover',
}

const initialState: NotificationState = {
    show: false,
    status: 'info',
    title: '',
    message: '',
    position: 'popover',
};

export const notificationSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'notification',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        show: (state, action: PayloadAction<NotificationState>) => {
            state = action.payload;
        },
        hide: (state) => {
            state.show = false;
        },
        toggle: (state) => {
            state.show = !state.show;
        },
    },
});

const { actions, reducer } = notificationSlice;
export const { show, hide, toggle } = actions;
export const selectNotification = (state: RootState) => state.notification;
export default reducer;
```

that would control how the notice shows, what position, what alert colors are used, etc.

However, now that I'm getting down to the implementation, I'm finding that I want to show notifications based on other features' state. For example, in my `blog-posts` feature, I fetch data from the server via a `thunk` and I'd like to set a notification based on the state of the thunk:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
        .addCase(fetchBlogPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'idle';
            state.entities = action.payload;
        })
        // hopefully this will apply to any failed / pending request
        .addMatcher(isRejectedAction, (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.error;
            // store.dispatch(show({
            //     show: true,
            //     status: 'error',
            //     title: 'Request Failed',
            //     message: action.error.message,
            //     position: 'popover',
            //     autoHide: false,
            //     confirm: false,
            // }));
        })
        .addMatcher(isPendingAction, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading';
        })
}
```

The obvious problem is that you're not supposed to dispatch action from reducers. Is this just a bad idea in general, or is there a way to set the `notification` state from a thunk response? Is there a "best practices" way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, I think you need to flip the implementation approach.

You could have the notifications slice add an `extraReducers` case that listens for any "rejected" action, and show a notification based on that action.  Multiple reducers handling one action is a pattern we specifically encourage:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. No idea why that hadn't occurred to me!